# A basic website on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to put a basic website on a linux image on S3.  I am guessing just for the image that will be a 2 Gig charge roughly (OS, mysql if that is possible, glassfish etc).  So lets say no one visits my site would I only be charged for the storage and the compute time it took for me to deploy my app?  Or like azure do they charge per hr just for your instance being present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 only stores and serves files -- you don't get any ability to run processes.  You might be thinking of Amazon EC2, which gives you a proper VM to run your programs in.  Those are billed by the hour whenever the VM is running.

Comment: So no matter what you can expect to have a website that will cost you about $21 a month

Comment: unless the website is only Statics (HTML,JS, CSS, Images etc) then the whole thing can run out of S3 for a few bucks :)

Comment: @DrewKhoury: I'm not aware of any Glassfish/MySQL-based sites that are entirely static content.

Comment: Didn't catch that part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing two Amazon services:

S3 provides the storage where you store the machine-image. S3 is billed for the amount of storage you use and the time that you store it.

You use the machine-image stored on S3 to start an EC2 instance. This instance is changed per hour as long as it runs.

If your EC2 image crashes, or is shut down, any data on it is lost, unless it is saved to storage. Since storing data from EC2 to S3 isn't really easy, and isn't well-suited for databases and such, Amazon provides EBS, a kind of virtual hard-disk that you attach to your instance. You'd usually use this hard-disk to store your MySQL database, logs, website, and other data that can change.

In effect, you pay for S3 (to store the machine-image and any relatively static data such as images), EC2 to run the instance and EBS to get the virtual hard-disk.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is billed by stored, uploaded and downloaded data. EC2 is billed for whenever the virtual machine is running.